# to how can I do web scraping to get prices for my products which I have ony google spreadsheet? dynamically queries

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

could you please give me an idea about how I can get thi

Comment: whats the url??

Answer (score 1):

Many sites go to great lengths to actively prevent scraping.  Giving you just the data you want entirely undermines their business model.  If you're a consumer, they're denied the chance to show you advertising.  If you're a reseller, you can use fairly simple programming and marketing to undercut their prices.

If you find yourself unable to scrape, it may be because it's not going to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, that won't be possible because the site is controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't understand/import JS. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given link and you will see a blank page:

[image: 0]

Comment: you can try different site. or ms excel with vba script that is able to scrape JS as I heard

Answer (score 0):

A workaround. You can import the data with the following script (credits to Brad Jasper) : [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/ae64c908b82cc8cf8840e176930ad937883fbe37/ImportJSON.gs), then request with `QUERY` formula. This is an example with "iPhone 8" and "Playstation 4".

[image: ijs]

In column A, you write the product to search. The url to get the JSON data is automatically  build in column B with a concat operator.

```
="https://wss2.cex.uk.webuy.io/v3/boxes?q="&A2
```

In column C, you have the `QUERY` formula combined with the `ImportJSON` data step.

```
=QUERY(ImportJSON(B2);"SELECT Col4,Col20 WHERE Col4 CONTAINS 'Plus' AND Col4 CONTAINS '64' AND Col4 CONTAINS 'Unlocked' LIMIT 1 label Col4'',Col20''";1)
```

`Col4` : product description, `Col20` : price of the product. Since the JSON will return a lot of results (multiple iPhone 8 versions), this is the step where you can refine your search. I've searched for "Plus","64" and "Unlocked" in the product description.

Comment: This is the sheet I've used (sell price is returned, it's the 20th column of the JSON): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q88_hHKmIWTzikRxY9cM_ZkM4xS4eicfN9C8rqvsunQ/edit?usp=sharing